# Why is the Federal Reserve allowed to "coin Money" and define exchange rates?

Tags: us-constitution, banking, currency

According the to United States Constitution [Article 1 Section 8](http://constitutionus.com/#a1s8),

> The Congress shall have Power To coin Money, regulate the Value thereof, and of foreign Coin, ...

But it is the Federal Reserve, not Congress, who is currently "coins Money" and defines exchange rates for foreign currencies.

Why isn't it a constitutional violation?

Comment: It's a bit hard for any single country to define exchange rates for foreign currencies, especially if the other country isn't cooperating. Chalk that one up to a misunderstanding of economics.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a violation because Congress [created and gave](https://www.federalreserve.gov/aboutthefed/fract.htm) the Federal Reserve the power to issue Federal Reserve Notes in the Federal Reserve Act which created the Federal Reserve. More here on the relationship between Congress and the Fed: https://www.bloomberg.com/view/articles/2017-09-27/how-congress-governs-the-federal-reserve.

Comment: Does it mean that Congress had transferred its consitutional right to "coin Money" to the private bank in 1913?

Comment: Well, only the Treasury department prints money, so no. Saying the Fed prints money is misnomer. The economic growth, for one example, produced by high liquidity caused by certain Fed policies (e.g. expansive monetary policy) is like adding money to the money supply and when the Fed purchases Treasury bonds and various securities from banks and replaces them with credit, it is like "printing money." However, no violation of any Constitutional provision.

Comment: coin Money does not mean only "print" these days of electronic money as you correctly notes, but anyway - the Treasury belongs to executive branch, not to legislative one. Isn't it a consitutional violation?

Comment: Congress only runs into a delegation problem if the guidelines it provides administrative agencies is too vague so that it essentially has delegated legislative power. If it sets up the structure and allows agencies to fill in the details (simplified explanation), then it will not be seen as a delegation of legislative power and will not be a violation .

Comment: You mean that until the Treasury prints only US dollars (i.e. does not print euro for example)  it is ok? The quantity to be printed the Treasury can decide on its own? Even if would act as the treasury of Venezuella (hyperinflation)??

Comment: @zer0hedge he Fed certainly isn't private. It's a public-private partnership overseen by an independent regulatory agency of the United States whose members are federal officers appointed by the President by and with the advice and consent of the Senate.

Comment: Good point, @cpast. Zero, I don't know what you are distinguishing there, because why would the US Treasury print euros ever under any circumstances? The way this all operates is a give-and-take of interest rates, debt, securities, etc. Far too much to explain to its fullest extent here. The Treasury prints how much it needs to print to fulfill its duties of ensuring the nation's financial security.

Comment: @cpast According to Worldbank "there is no one widely accepted definition of public-private partnerships". Google coudn't find someone calling the Fed "public private partnership", sorry. Could you please elaborate your comment as the answer to my question?

Comment: @A.fm. I just tried to understand what do you mean by "vague guidelines" , i.e. what is vague and what is not vague.

Comment: @zer0hedge it’s like many cases, extremely fact dependent.

Comment: @zer0hedge In all cases under Article I, Section 8, "The Congress shall have the power to . . . " means that the "Congress shall have the power to enact legislation to be carried out by the Executive Branch to . . . " The phase was never contemplated to mean that members of Congress would, for example, run printing presses to print currency.

Comment: @A.fm. Just to let you know - it is not Treasury who prints dollars, but the Fed https://www.federalreserve.gov/paymentsystems/coin_currency_orders.htm.

Comment: Hi @zer0hedge - just to let *you* know, no. You're wrong, even according to your own link! 

Comment: @A.fm. No, I'm right. BEP is just a factory. Your iPhone is produced by Apple, not by unknown Chinese manufacturer)

Comment: @zer0hedge, you're either trolling or not qualified to speak to these issues. First, your analogy doesn't work. Apple doesn't monitor the level of iPhones and simply put in orders for more. That's what the Fed does w/r/t U.S. currency. Since, of course, you said "prints" and not "coordinates" or "monitors," you're wrong. Bureau of Engraving and Printing, which is in the U.S. Department of Treasury, "is one of the largest currency printing operations in the world," according to its website.